# Titlesec error when using macros defined using \@ifstar in section titles

Tags: macros, titlesec

I am using `titlesec` and would like to use a macro that has a star variant in the title of a paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\def\something{\@ifstar{A}{B}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\paragraph{A \something\ title} Lipsum.
\end{document}
```

This however returns an error

```
mwe.tex:9: Argument of \ttl@assign@i has an extra }. [\paragraph{A \something\ title}]
mwe.tex:9: Paragraph ended before \ttl@assign@i was complete. [\paragraph{A \something\ title}]
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Macros using `\@ifstar` are fragile. So you need `\protect` or should use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\def`. Alternatively I would suggest to use `\NewDocumentCommand\something{s}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{A}{B}}`.

Comment: BTW: The problem has (almost) nothing to do with using `\titlesec`. Without you would still have an error—just another one.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736

Comment: @cabohah oh thanks! I did try to use `\protect` but another mistake was masking the fix! Sorry for the duplicate